# Is there a way changing actual value of an int without creating a new instance?

Tags: python-3.x

I assigned an int to a variable and I changed its value by `*=` operator. I realized, however, that Python3 assigned a new object to the variable not changing the original one.

This is the code I ran:

```
>>> a=5
>>> b=a
>>> a*=7
>>> print(a)
35
>>> print(b)
5
```

Is there a way that change the original object's value which the variable holds without assigning a new object by using `*=` operator?

Comment: for what purpose? by any chance you wish to change an argument int from inside a function?

Comment: I have read the post you suggested. In the post, it is stated that int is immutable. Hence, it cannot be changed. Thanks!